# proc sql for count and percent

Tags: count, sas, percentage, proc-sql

```
proc sql noprint;
    create table M_S as 
    select a.SUBJID,b.EXDSTXT,a.SEX,,

            case when SEX= 'M' then 'Male'
                 when SEX= 'F' then 'Female'
                 else ''
                 end as sexcatvar,

            case when b.EXDSTXT='7 ug/kg/day' then 1
                 when b.EXDSTXT='9 ug/kg/day' then 2
                 when b.EXDSTXT='12 ug/kg/day' then 3
                 when b.EXDSTXT='Total' then 4
                 else .
                 end as EXDSN
from Sasfile.Dm as a 
inner join EX as b 
on a.SUBJID=b.SUBJID
;
quit;
```

desired table:
[image]

I need to find the count of sex*exdstxt as well as the percentage of that count. This is what I tried. The count is correct but not the percent shown as pct

```
proc sql noprint;
    create table FREQST as
        select sexcatvar,EXDSN,EXDSTXT,count(sexcatvar) as COUNT,calculated COUNT/ (select count(*) from M_S) as pct format=percent8.2
        from M_S
        group by sexcatvar,EXDSN,EXDSTXT
        order by EXDSTXT;
quit;
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use left join for example:

```
proc sql noprint;
    create table FREQST as
        select sexcatvar,EXDSN,EXDSTXT,count(sexcatvar) as COUNT,calculated COUNT/ count_all  as pct format=percent8.2
        from M_S left join (select count(*) as count_all from M_S) on 1=1
        group by sexcatvar,EXDSN,EXDSTXT
        order by EXDSTXT;
quit;
```